# Structuring the state in a Vuex Store

Tags: javascript, flux, vuex

I recently started learning Vuex and I would like to have some insight on how to properly structure the state of a Vuex/Flux-like stores

Lets take a look at the example below

```
ProductStore

state: {
  name: 'some name',
  price: 'some price',
  variants: [],
  selectedVariant: {},
}

mutations: {
  [ADD_VARIANT] (state, newVariant) {
    state.variants.push(newVariant)
  }

  [DELETE_VARIANT] (state, deletedId) {
    state.variants = _.filter(state.variants, c => c.id == deleteID )
  }

  [EDIT_VARIANT] (state, editedComment) {
    //...
  }

  [EDIT_SELECTED_VARIANT_TYPE] (state, variantType) {
    state.selectedVariant.type = variantType
  }
}
```

How do you structure states in instances like the one above when you have a parentComponent of sorts(the `Product`) and you have to manage childComponent states as well(the `Variant`).

In my specific instance, I have a `ProductPage`. In it, I have a `VariantTable`. Selecting an item in the `VariantTable` brings up a `VariantModal` that lets you edit variant attributes which should propagate to the parent table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize your store's state. If Product-Variant relationship is pure 1-n, the store's state can be:

```
state: {
  name: 'some name',
  price: 'some price',
  variants: [
    { variantId: 'V1', ProductId: 'P1' },
    ...
  ],
  selectedVariant: {},
  products: [
    { productId: 'P1' },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Then with [Vuex's action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html) you can add an action to handle update both Variant and Product together:

```
..., // state goes above
mutations: {
  ...
  [EDIT_PRODUCT] (args) => { ... }
},
actions: {
  [EDIT_PRODUCT_VARIANT] ({ commit, state }, editedComment) {
    // take extra data if need via state
    commit([EDIT_VARIANT], editedComment);
    commit([EDIT_PRODUCT], { productId: editedComment.ProductId })
  }
}
```

The point is to avoid data duplication and nested data as much as possible, while allowing data to be updated fast and efficiently.

Read more about data normalization at [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)